# Running DXL script in Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: javascript, batch-file, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, ibm-doors

Please anyone let me know how to build a DXL script using Jenkins Pipeline? I'm using the below script however it's neither failing nor executing the script to get the desired outputs. Below is the pipeline script I'm using and also I'm passing some inputs inside the script through text document. Inputs are the DOORS module address on which the script should work.

```js
pipeline {
    agent any
    environment {
        // Get the Jenkins DOORS username & password from the credential repository
        userpwd = credentials('jenkinsdoors')
    }
    stages {
        stage('Initialization') {
            steps {
                dir('.\\reports') {
                    // This particular script generates a results file.
                    // Delete the old results files so we know if it worked or not.
                    bat('del /Q \*')
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Run DXL') {
            steps {
                // Run the command line, passing in the username and password of the Jenkins DOORS account
                bat script: '''
                    C:\\IBM\\Rational\\DOORS\\9.6\\bin\\doors.exe -u "%userpwd_USR%" -P "%userpwd_PSW%"  -b \\\\path\\to\\script\\test.dxl
                '''
            }
        }
//      stage('Verify') {
//          steps {
//              script {
//                  // Check if the results file exists, so we know if the job worked
//                  if (!fileExists('.\\reports\\JENKINS.LOG')) {
//                      echo 'JENKINS.LOG was not generated.'
//                      currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'
//                  }
//                  else {
//                      // The file exists - dump the contents of the file to the output log
//                      bat script: 'type .\\reports\\JENKINS.LOG'
//                  }
//              }
//          }
//      }
    }
}
```

Comment: what happens when you open a command line window, cd to c:\temp and start `C:\IBM\Rational\DOORS\9.6\bin\doors.exe -u "%userpwd_USR%" -P "%userpwd_PSW%"  -b \\path\to\script\test.dxl`?

Comment: Issue is with the excel.application that I'm calling in DXL script. Jenkins is having issue to open excel application in server. Needs to be fixed by Jenkins admin and restart is required.

Comment: Through command prompt my dxl works. In fact it's a good idea to solve erros in cmd before going to Jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

ok, so your issue should be solved now. Next time you might start investigating with a simple batch dxl script c:\temp\sayHello.dxl

```
Stream stm = append ("c:\\temp\\hello.txt")
string now = stringOf dateOf intOf today
stm << "Hello on " now "\n"
close stm
```

to see whether

- doors starts
- username and password is correct
- batch file is found and executed

Comment: That's correct way of checking. you're right mike.

Comment: Now there is another issue with Jenkins which doesn't build the script with timestamp. If timestamp is induced it will not generate output. Why?

Comment: please provide more input here or better create a new question. Where exactly is the timestamp included?